# Upgrade 20.04 to 20.10 fails UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 20.10

do-release-upgrade throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-pi67sg1k/groovy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-pi67sg1k/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-pi67sg1k/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2089, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-pi67sg1k/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1926, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-pi67sg1k/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 966, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.tasks = self.cache.installedTasks
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-pi67sg1k/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 823, in installedTasks
    for line in pkg._pcache._records.record.split("\n"):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 1030: invalid start byte
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 477, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 430, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-pi67sg1k/groovy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-pi67sg1k/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-pi67sg1k/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2089, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-pi67sg1k/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1926, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-pi67sg1k/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 966, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.tasks = self.cache.installedTasks
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-pi67sg1k/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 823, in installedTasks
    for line in pkg._pcache._records.record.split("\n"):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 1030: invalid start byte
➜  ~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager-core/+bug/1453740) in ubuntu 14.04, I figure that it's a package issue.

"After do-release-update exited with a similar to the above message, there is a temporary ubuntu-release-upgrader-{random} left over in /tmp.

- Enter that directory i.e. cd /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-asd123
- edit DistUpgradeCache.py
- Head down to `def installedTasks(self)`
- after the line that reads: `for pkg in self:`
- add `print(pkg)`"

after finding the troublesome package,
which is the last package before the error (for me it was `intel-openvino-runtime-ubuntu18-2019.3.376`)

`apt-get remove` the package

Comment: the pkg wasn't printed in any place, how do you discover the package? Thanks!

Comment: @LeandroA.Siqueira I've edited DistUpgradeCache.py and added a print(pkg) .. after that I saw the package that was trublesome

Comment: After I edit DistUpgradeCache.py, how do I run it? I tried python DistUpgradeCache.py and it came back with missing apt module.